# Datos enviados en una petición Ajax no llegan al controladorr

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

Es la primera vez que intento hacer un método `POST` con `fetch` (no lo he hecho tampoco con `ajax`), estuve viendo alguno códigos pero la verdad me perdí mas de lo que pensé.

Lo que estoy queriendo hacer es enviar datos de 2 `input` que están en el formulario (modal) al controlador, pero sin recargar la pagina.

**BLADE**

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="{{route("add_notas")}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="modal fade" id="AddNotas" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AddNotasLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="AddNotasLabel">Agregar una nota</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Titulo:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control-custom" id="recipient-name" name="titulo" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="descrp-text" class="col-form-label">Descripción:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control-custom" id="descrp-text" name="concepto" required></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="enviar"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
let boton = document.getElementById("enviar");

boton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var titulo = document.getElementById("recipient-name").value;
    var concepto = document.getElementById("descrp-text").value;

    var datos_form = {titulo: titulo,  concepto: concepto, };

    fetch('{{route("add_notas")}}',{
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(datos_form)
        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });
});
```

**RUTA**

```
Route::post('/dashboard/agregar/notas/post','ControladorNotas@add_notas')->name('add_notas');
```

**CONTROLADOR**

```
 public function add_notas(Request $datos){
   DB::table('tabla_notas')->insert([
      'titulo' => $datos->titulo;,
      'concepto' => $datos->concepto;
   ]);
   return 'ok';
 }
```

1. Normalmente eso es lo que hago cuando hago un `POST`.
2. El `return` siempre redirecciono al `.Blade` en este caso no se si tenga que retornar igual al mismo `Blade` a otro lado o usar algún método `JSON` etc... como comente al inicio primera vez haciendo esto.

EDIT:

aclarando el problema.

1. No me guarda en la `BDD`.
2. Se recarga la pagina (no quiero eso).

Comment: pues no me funciona.. no se si estoy recibiendo mal los datos en el controlador, se me recarga la pagina.

Comment: @BetaM si eso hice, y manda error. `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

Comment: @BetaM muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Primero deberías quitar el atributo `action` de tu formulario, pues ya desde `fetch` estás indicando la ruta a la que va a apuntar tu petición.
- Posterior, el objeto que pasas como segundo argumento a la función `fetch` también acepta una clave que se llama: [`headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) la cual a su vez es otro objeto y dentro del cual indicaremos el paso del token [`csrf`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf) que esta declarado en tu formulario y que debe viajar en la petición para que laravel la considere fiable y la procese.
- Finalmente usaremos el constructor FormData para concentrar y enviar los datos por la petición AJAX
- Dado que la API de fetch trabaja o esta contruida sobre promesas, debes acceder a las respuestas que esta te ofrece tanto si fue resuelta como si hubo un problema de red

  - Con `data.exito` leemos la respuesta del servidor, accediendo a la clave `exito` que declaramos en el backend de Laravel

Prueba tu petición de esta forma:

```
let boton = document.getElementById("enviar");
let csrf  = document.querySelector("input[name='_token']");
let titulo = document.getElementById("recipient-name");
let concepto = document.getElementById("descrp-text");

boton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    let datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('titulo', titulo.value);
    datos.append('concepto', concepto.value);
    
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch('{{route("add_notas")}}',{
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf.value
        },
        body: datos
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.exito);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
    })
});
```

Por cierto a nivel de tu controlador, la respuesta se construiría de esta forma:

```
public function add_notas(Request $datos){
   $alta = DB::table('tabla_notas')->insert([
              'titulo' => $datos->titulo;,
              'concepto' => $datos->concepto;
              /*
                si tu tabla tiene las columnas de created_at y updated_at
                debes también en el insert asignarles un valor
              */
           ]);
   if($alta)
   {
        return response()->json(["exito" => "registrado"]);
   }
 }
```

De modo que cuando procesas la petición puedas recuperar la clave `exito` y pintes el mensaje que tiene asociado en la vista

Comment: Pues por lo visto ese no es el problema, sigue igual :/

Comment: guardaba solo cuando estaba el `action` en el `<form>` pero eso era obvio, con js recargando o no sigue igual, no guarda datos.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tfrlho

Comment: ok, muchas gracias!

Comment: Efectivamente, ya guarda en la `BDD`  https://prnt.sc/tfs5i3

Comment: ahora una pregunta, no se si seria de formular otra pregunta o es con esta misma,
como puedo hacer para que se muestre sin recargar de nuevo la pagina ?

Comment: osea, guarda en la `BDD` pero tengo que igual recargar para poder visualizar el dato

Comment: ok amigo, muchas gracias!